# How to submit a file to paste.ubuntu.com without graphical interface?

Tags: command-line, curl, pastebin

My GUI does not work. I can only see a text terminal. I would like to send my logs to [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com) but I don't know how. Without a graphical interface, I am lost.

Is there any way to submit a file to pastebin without needing any GUI?

Answer (score 16):

There are many ways, of course, but I start with one which is simple to explain: it just requires some command line magic. I assume that there is internet connection (check it for example with `ping -c 5 google.com`. Also, I assume that `/my/file` is the location of file you would like to submit, and JohnDoe is your askubuntu nickname.

1. The simplest of it all, but you need to install pastebinit first:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pastebinit
   pastebinit -i /my/file
   ```
2. Submit using curl. For that, curl must be installed.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install curl
   curl -v --data-urlencode "content@/my/filename" -d "poster=JohnDoe" -d "syntax=text" http://paste.ubuntu.com
   ```

   You will see some output, with one of the lines looking more or less like that:

   ```
   < Location: http://paste.ubuntu.com/123456789/
   ```

   This is the link you need to share.
3. There is a number of text-only web browsers, for example `w3m`. Run these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install w3m
   w3m http://paste.ubuntu.com
   ```

   You move around with a cursor. When you come to the text area and press "Enter", w3m will ask you which editor to use; choose `nano`. Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to read in the file.
4. Your USB sticks still work. Insert an USB stick and type `mount` to see at what location it has been mounted. Say, you see that it is `/media/MyStick`. You can copy the file using command line

   ```
   cp /my/file /media/MyStick
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner that uses dpaste.com:

```
curl -s -F "content=<MY_LOGFILE" https://dpaste.com/api/
```

That `curl` command will return a URL that will display the contents of `MY_LOGFILE`.

*(Disclosure: I run dpaste.com.)*

Answer (score 1):

using `curl`

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -fsSL -X POST \
    --url https://paste.ubuntu.com \
    --output /dev/null \
    --write-out "%{url_effective}\n" \
    --data-urlencode "content@${PASTEBIN_CONTENT:-/dev/stdin}" \
    --data "poster=${PASTEBIN_POSTER:-`whoami`@`hostname`}" \
    --data "syntax=${PASTEBIN_SYNTAX:-text}" \
    --data "expiration=${PASTEBIN_EXPIRATION:-day}"
```

1. saving into **pastebin.sh**
2. `chmod u+x pastebin.sh`
3. `./pastebin.sh < file-name` or `cat file | ./pastebin.sh`

and after running it, it gives you an output like this:

`https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kK3xxKHs3c/`

---

NOTE
for expiration *day* can be:

- week
- month
- year

[source](https://etherarp.net/command-line-pastebin-using-curl/index.html)

Answer (score -2):

pastebinit by default uses pastebin.com

instead you can use gist. you need to install Ruby first then install gist gem

gem install gist

https://github.com/defunkt/gist

Comment: The version of `pastebinit` in Ubuntu uses http://paste.ubuntu.com by default, because [when you invoke it with the `-b` flag it uses a distro-specific default](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pastebinit.1.html). As the manpage says: "-b [pastebin url] (default is distro-specific with a fallback to pastebin.com)" I use `pastebinit` from Ubuntu's repositories regularly; when I don't use the `-b` flag, my pastes always go to http://paste.ubuntu.com.